# How to convert a regular Google AdSense Ad in a responsive ad automatically using preg_match?

Tags: javascript, php, preg-match, adsense

- WordPress Theme options panel.
- A textarea field where a user enter its non-responsive AdSense code.

I need that if a user enter a non-responsive adsense code, that code to be converted in a responsive code as follow:

NON REPONSIVE CODE:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- non responsive ads -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-12345"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

THE ABOVE CODE NEED TO BE CONVERTED IN:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:block"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-12345"
data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

I guess the job can be done using `preg_match` but how?

Thanks.

Comment: What about adding a css rule for `.adsbygoogle`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that (as far I know).

That (non-responsive) unit configuration is *stored* on Google servers:

```
{
  "status": "ACTIVE", 
  "kind": "adsense#adUnit", 
  "code": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
  "name": "non responsive ads", 
  "savedStyleId": "qwertzuiopšđžasdfghjklyxcvbnmqwerfvbgtzhnmjgbvfredcxsw", 
  "contentAdsSettings": {
    "type": "TEXT_IMAGE", 
    "backupOption": {
      "type": "BLANK"
    }, 
    "size": "SIZE_728_90"
  }, 
  "id": "ca-pub-12345:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

pagead2.googlesyndication.com will consider `data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` ad requests as request for `SIZE_728_90` format, and you can't change that "on the fly" - you need to create another ad unit if you need another `size`.

Even if you would do it and it looks like "it works", it is still a violation of AdSense policies, and it would pose a risk for all involved AdSense accounts and ad serving on your site. (Because "converted" code will make you some percent of invalid ad impressions, and / or bad requests.)

Modification of the AdSense ad code
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en

Create a responsive ad unit
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893?hl=en